# Android local language

Tags: android, localization

I know that the multiple language support can be obtained by maintaining different    **strings.xml**  in  folders like *values ,  values-it*('it' incase of italian)  and the app will show the contents in the language which is the device's language . My question is I have my app , that people of my region would like in local language [[Marathi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marathi_language) / [Hindi]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindi_language) .  Initially I will provide screen that would allow me to choose English/Hindi/Marathi .I am struck , how to programmatically apply them !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set your selected `Language` on this way:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("YourSelectedLang");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: "YourSelectedLang" will be "en" in case of English. For Hindi and Marathi, you have to find the codes on Google, because I don't know them... ;)

Comment: For the Hindi the code is `HI` and for Marathi the code is `MR`

Comment: Fantastic. If I'll ever need those languages, now I know which are the locales ;)

Comment: @MD If we have change the app language then if we have some searching option within app, and if we search in that then, how app will show data, should we develop some different database for each language or some android code setting is there so that app could show data according to search ?